# the image in Image component not getting fully strectched

Tags: react-native

```
return(

<TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',backgroundColor:'transparent',flexDirection:'column',...this.props.style}}
>
<ImageBackground
  source={this.state.backimage}

resizeMode={'cover'}
style={{ flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',

    justifyContent:'center'}}

>

<Text  ref={this.textref}style={{color:this.state.textcolor,position:'absolute',alignSelf:'center',fontSize:this.props.fontSize,fontWeight:this.props.fontWeight}}>{this.state.textintial}</Text>
</ImageBackground>

</TouchableOpacity>

)
```

[image: this image]

You can see the book touchable opacity  inside that and  **component** height  is fine but width not stretched fully, i have tried  changing all the enum values of resize mode  attribute but nothing seems to work fine

Comment: can you share how you define `...this.props.style`? it would be the place i will look.

Answer (score 0):

try set imageStyle

```
 <ImageBackground
    imageStyle={{
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      overflow: 'visible',
   }}
   style={{ overflow: 'visible',
          resizeMode: 'contain'}}>
```